# Multi-level sorting of collections

Tags: collections, plone

How would I go about adding another level of sorting to collections.

Example: A real estate site has listings of properties for sale. The listings are achieved using Collections. Sold properties need to be at the bottom of the list but the rest need to be sorted by price.

Answer (score 3):

http://plone.org/products/collective.flexitopic

does this in the javascript land. If it ok for you. Otherwise this index:

http://www.dieter.handshake.de/pyprojects/zope/#ManagableIndex

could help you to create a new field to sort the collection.

Another approach could be to give to sold properties a negative price and not display it, so sorting would work as expected.

Comment: forgot: http://pypi.python.org/pypi/Products.AdvancedQuery/3.0.1
"AdavancedQuery supports sorting on arbitrary levels of field indexes"

Answer (score 1):

You can't without additional coding. You'd have to manually sort the catalog query results after retrieving them, as the Zope catalog does not support multi-level sorting by itself. Depending on your result set size, this could be quite in-effecient as well.

If you want to go this route, you would have to either subclass the ATContentTypes.content.topic.ATTopic class and override the queryCatalog method, or create new skin versions of the topic views to call a different method that in turn then calls queryCatalog so you can apply additional sorting to it.

Needless to say, this requires some Plone and python expertise.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a nested Collection. Like in default Events Collection, that has a "Past events" collection.
I believe you can't display the nested collection's objects in the same listing, but at least you see a "Past events" big link.

With this approach, you should exclude sold properties from initial collection (`sold` must be an index in your catalog) and include only sold properties in the nested one.

Comment: Would it then be possible to create a new browser view that would display the items from both the collection and the subcollection on the same page?